# How do I use the folder path that a user selects and use that path when they download files?

Tags: vb.net

I'm in the process of creating a launcher for a game with Visual Basic and I have pretty much everything done except many people may have files in different drives. So, I want them to select a file path then when they have selected that path I want the download button to download the files that the need downloaded to the selected directory. I was thinking that the beginning of the code would be something like this:

```
Form2.TextBox1.Text
```

and then something else after that in the buttons code.

I hope I'm being specific enough.

P.S. The reason why this is an issue is because if I use `System.Diagnostic.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\[remaining folderpath here]")` to launch the .exe then the program will only look for the files in that directory even though some people may have the files in their D: drives, etc. And, I have a `FolderDialog` setup and working.

Comment: dont make users type in a path; use a `FolderBrowserDialog`; dont store their selection in a `TextBox` use a variable

Comment: Would you be able to supply an example of the code for the variable? Plus, I already have the `FolderBrowserDialog` there for users to select their folder path.

Comment: `Private UserFolder As String`  you could pull up almost any random VB Q or A to see how to declare a variable.

Comment: You can use `My.Settings` to store path after close application.